# Drag a link into a batch file

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, drag-and-drop, cmd

I like using %1 in my batch files, but dragging a link over from the browser (Chrome) doesn't work.
My batch file is

```
echo %1
pause
```

How can I make it accept dragged links?

Comment: note the puase is ofcourse in the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Dragging links from the browser around seems to be a little magic. Apparently the browser only handles dragging a link into a folder where an appropriate shortcut will be created. Passing the link around as an argument doesn't seem to be possible. You can also notice this when dragging links into other applications. It won't work.

So I'm afraid there is no way how you can accept dragged links from a browser window.

Comment: any possible hack you can think of?
i notice what your saying as i work with diffrent browsers each has some different anomaly regarding dragged links.

Comment: This probably depends solely on the browser. As far as I know The drag source and drop target work together in some kind of magic to decide whether something can be dropped. And in this case dropping seemingly only works in folders, but not on executables/batch files. At least with IE and FF.